# URL is being truncated when it is too long

Tags: java, jsp, url, jakarta-ee

In JSP, I am passing URL:

```
http://gmail.com/fs-bin/click?id=VFS63JhSk2k&offerid=99133.10000176&subid=0&u1=1945&type=4
```

To the server. But in server side, when get the URL from request, `req.getParameter("url")`, I am getting only:

```
http://gmail.com/fs-bin/click?id=VFS63JhSk2k
```

How to get the entire URL?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see your `getParameter` is splitting at first `&`? This is because a URL like http://myserver.com/test.jsp?param1=val1&url=http://gmail.com/fs-bin/click?id=VFS63JhSk2k&offerid=99133.10000176&subid=0&u1=1945&type=4&paramlast=valLast will be assumed as a URL with paramerers

```
param1=val1
url=http://gmail.com/fs-bin/click?id=VFS63JhSk2k
offerid=99133.10000176
subid=0
u1=1945
type=4
paramlast=valLast
```

You need to escape `&` in your JSP before you pass this URL as paramter. One of the may ways is

```
 URLEncoder.encode("http://gmail.com/fs-bin/click?id=VFS63JhSk2k&offerid=99133.10000176&subid=0&u1=1945&type=4", "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the url before using it. To replace the & and other especial URL characters before passing it out as parameter

//Before passing it as parameter

```
    String url = "http://a.com?a=1&b=2&c=3";
    String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8"); 
    System.out.println(" http://anotherdomain.com/page.jsp?url=" + encodedUrl);
```

//on JSP

```
    String decodedUrl = URLDecoder.decode(req.getParameter("url"),"UTF-8"); 
    System.out.println("Dncoded URL " + decodedUrl);
```

Answer (score -1):

`URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());` will give you the whole URL.

You can also get specific parts of the URL. Check java docs for java.net.URL.

Comment: Wrong - from the Javadoc "The returned URL contains a protocol, server name, port number, and server path, but it does not include query string parameters. "

Comment: @JimGarrison: you are correct. It does not include query string parameters. My bad.

Comment: Thanks all for your information.one more way to avoid this by addingor imcrementing the parameter "maxHttpHeaderSize" in Tomcat_Homepath/conf/server.xml